# Admob banner doesn't display in production mode

Tags: android, admob

I am integrating admob in my application, using [this tutorial](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/integrating-new-google-admob-banner-interstitial-ads/). In debug mode, the Admob test banner ad is showing as expected. However, upon removing `.addTestDevice("XXXXXXXXXXXXX")` and building a signed APK, the real ad doesn't display. Instead the log displays the following:

```
07-07 16:10:23.743: I/Ads(20143): Starting ad request.
07-07 16:10:23.743: I/Ads(20143): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("B2D638A0Bxxx024D83BE163E0E") to get test ads on this device.
```

**Java Code:**

```
 AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    // Add a test device to show Test Ads
    //.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    //.addTestDevice("B2D638A0BEEXXX4024D83BE163E0E")
    .build();
    // Load ads into Banner Ads
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

**XML layout:**

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-96XXXXXXXX83/25383XX455" />
```

Interstitial ads are also integrated into this app and they're displaying perfectly both in debug- and production mode. Why are banners not displaying in production mode?

**Found The Solution:**

You must create separate ids for banner and Interstitial.While creating an ad-unit a small tab will be opened,if you select banner then an id representing a banner will be created and same goes for Interstitial.I was using Interstitial ID while creating the banner and as a result banner containing Real ads was not showing up.

Comment: How long ago did you test this? Because if I'm not mistaken, AdMob will only populate the banners with ads after they have been some time in production mode. So it should be more than a couple of hours in production mode to be sure it doesn't work.

Comment: Show more log. There is always log about the AdResponse. Show that.